# Why do Chabad men look like non-Chassidim in several respects?

Tags: minhag, clothing, chasidut-hasidism, haircuts

As the comments began, I did two Google image searches.

When I searched "Hasidic man," this was the first result.
[image]

When I searched "Misnagdim," this was the first result.
[image]

That second picture illustrated an article called "[Misnagdim versus Chassidim](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/1908539/misnagdim-versus-chassidim-shmini-atzeres.html)."

It seems to me that in several respect, Chabad men tend to resemble non-Chassidim.

- Many Chassidim wear frock-coats (*kapotes* or *bekeshers*) every day,
  weekdays included, and often with a belt (*gartle*). For non-Chassidim and Chabadnics, American
  business suits seem more typical (although the non-Chassidim wear ties).
- Many Chassidim wear fur hats (*streimels* or *spodik*) on Shabbos. For non-Chassidim and Chabadnics, fedoras seem more typical.
- Many Chassidim wear knickers and white socks. For non-Chassidim and Chabadnics, pants typically reach the shoe and socks are black.

There are several other distinctions in appearance that come to mind, but I don't really know who does what. For example I’m not sure how haircuts and *peyos* interact with this pattern. People ask Chabadnics why we have short *peyos*; do they ask non-Chassidim that question? When I see someone with very short hair on the top of his head, but gigantic *peyos*, I tend to assume that he is a non-Chabad Chassid, rightly or wrongly. And what about those (seemingly) silver decorations on the large *tallis*, and the blue fringe?

While a piecewise explanation, different for each example, might be the truest explanation, I'm really wondering if there is some general explanation for the pattern I'm perceiving. And is it only for matters of appearance, or does Chabad stand with non-Chassidim on other matters too?

And I note: sometimes the world presents a pattern that is meaningful although imperfect. For example, if someone asked me why men have voices deeper in pitch than women's, it would of course occur to me to wonder whether it was *always* true. But that question might get in the way of the one intended.

Comment: Previous generations wore more conventional chassidic dress. The Rebbe wore a modern attire in his younger years which he was reluctant to change when he became Rebbe, so Chassidim adapted.

Comment: See also https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3755339/jewish/Why-Do-Many-Chassidim-Wear-Shtreimels-Fur-Hats.htm

Comment: @shmosel I'm not really clear how that answers the question. Are you saying that all all the distinctions I mention are simply the Rebbe's personal taste?

Comment: Regarding having short Payos, it follows the Arizal’s opinion, that according to Kabbalah, the payos should not go down to where the beard begins

Comment: @Chaim I'm not saying all of it, and I'm not necessarily attributing it to taste. The Rebbe didn't really speak about it. I'm just describing how it played out.

Comment: @שלום How would this explain why Chabad and non-Chassidim wound up on one side of the line, other Chassidim on the other side?

Comment: @Chaim - There are non-Chasidim with long Payos (like Yemenite Jews) as well, and those who don’t, is not necessarily because of the reason mentioned above

Comment: @שלום So you don't see the pattern that I'm suggesting?

Comment: Not with regards to Payos, at least

Comment: To address your final line, another difference with Chabad and a lot of other chassidic groups (with notable exceptions) is that Chabad tend to value intellectualism and a logical approach to chassidic ideas, many other groups have a more _chagas_, heart-felt approach. To address in general, another thing to consider is location and the overall history of Chabad compared to other groups. Them being in Russia, and also under communism, I am sure is fairly relevant. Much, I am sure, is also just coincidence.

Comment: A note to my Misnagdishe brothers: I believe that Rabbi Kaii has used a bit of Chabad jargon. Chabad is so-named after three sefiros Chochmah-Binah-Da'as. We sometimes refer to other Chassidim by the word Chagas, a word comparably formed from the "next" three sefiros Chessed-Gevurah-Tiferes.

Comment: Chabad is a Litvisher *chassidus*, as above.

Comment: Yes @Chaim, and it's also a gross oversimplification. As is what The GRAPKE said imo

Comment: This question should not have been closed for being “off-topic”. In the help center link provided to explain why a question might be off topic, it specifically says that if your question is about some Jewish practice(s), this is on topic and a good and valid question. The question is about specific Chabad practices. This should be reopened.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Judaism? Even by the standards of the Stack Exchange, that's a pretty silly observation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question, *as presented*, only relates to the current generation of Chabad men. But the essence of the answer is that like most Chassidim (*and for that matter, those you are calling "Misnagdim"*), many try to follow the practices (הנהגות) of their Rebbe.

All the distinctive practices you are taking note of in regard to Chabad today, are from the Rebbe of this generation, Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson.

There are various historical traditions within Chabad as to why the Rebbe adopted these changes in his own personal practice. But the "Chabad men" of today are following the Rebbe's practice. It is one way of being *connected to* (מקשר לרבי היינו ההתקשרות לרבי) the Rebbe.

On this concept, it should be noted that the Rebbe, when discussing this concept and practice always emphasized that the best and preferred method of being connected with the Rebbe was to learn his Chassidic discourses (מאמרים).

An excellent discussion of this subject can be found in [this linked article](http://www.chabad.org.il/Articles/Article.asp?ArticleID=1877&CategoryID=813) which begins with these words from [HaYom Yom for the 24th of Sivan](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43302&st=&pgnum=75):

> ההתקשרות האמיתית היא על-ידי לימוד התורה. כשהוא לומד את מאמרי החסידות שלי וקורא את השיחות
>
> The true connection is through study of the Torah. When one studies my Hasidic discourses and reads the talks...

And see also in [HaYom Yom](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43302&st=&pgnum=45&hilite=) for the [9th day of Adar-2](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60799&st=&pgnum=124), which says:

> גדול התשוקה להתקשרות,  יכול להשביע רק כאשר ילמוד מאמרי החסידות שאומר הרב וכותב, כי בראית פנים בלבד לא סגי.
>
> **The great desire for connection** (to the Rebbe) **can only be satisfied when one will learn the discourses of Chassidut that the Rebbe says and writes**, that following external appearances (*practices*) alone, is insufficient (*not enough*).

Comment: I feel I'm missing something here that everyone else is seeing. Your answer seems to be a rather formal one, that Chabadniks do what the Rebbe does, whatever that is, without sharing my curiosity about the specifics. Also, how do you know that Chabadnics before the Rayatz wore knickers and white socks or very short hair with huge peyos? There seems to be only one photograph of the Rashab (not looking particularly Chassidic, by the way), and few images of Chabadniks before the invention of photography.

Comment: @Chaim There are many paintings and photos of previous Rebbes of Chabad. There are also many photos of Chabad Chassidim of the last century too.  See for example the famous painting of the Tzemach Tzedek who wore all white, linen garments (like many Kabbalists), gartel and a fur trimmed, outer hat like a Spudik. Regarding the hat, so did the Rebbe Rayatz. Generally, the Rebbes wear the kaputah on special days (Shabbat, Yom Tov, etc.) and not on the regular days of the week. My answer is in response to your question, "I'm really wondering if there is some general explanation for the pattern".

Comment: By the way, I didn't actually call anyone "misnagdim" within the question. I used the word in the Google image search because I couldn't think of any alternative; and in one of the comments I used it the hopes of being amusing. But in the headline and the actual text of the question I said "non-Chassidim" eight times and never "misnagdim."

Comment: @Chaim Shavuah tov. Perhaps for you, the expression, “misnagdim”, means little or nothing. But for Reb Yisroel Salanter, the father of the Mussar movement, the 3rd Lubavitcher Rebbe, the Tzemach Tzedek and many others who strove to eliminate this false division within the Jewish people, it is not in any way “amusing”. It suggests that the Jewish people are not עם אחד בארץ and that they encamped at Mount Sinai not as one, but as many. There have been, and continue to be those who promote the false idea that the Jewish people are not one, in opposition to ועמך כלם צדיקים. See Sanhedrin 10:1

Answer (score 0):

Traditional Jewish dress and the growing of long peyos were curbed and outlawed in Russia and Russian controlled territories to various extents at various points in the 19th century. At that point the traditional dress which has been worn in Lita and Reissin and parts of Poland was modified. The Prince Albert Frock was adopted by Rabbonim regardless of Hasidic/Non-Hasidic affiliation. Peyos were either shortened or put behind the ear, under the yarmulka.

In certain professions and areas there was a push by the Russians to adopt German Dress (not only for the Yidden, the non-Jews also) and short jackets became prevalent by the early 1900's.

If one looks at pictures of Chabad yeshiva students from the interwar period one will see they look like Litvish style dress.

So the influence and style predates the nesius of The Rebbe.